# How to add RGB values into setColor() in Java?

Tags: java, rgb

How can I add (red, green, blue) values to my Java? For example:

```
 setColor(255, 0, 0);
```

The context looks like this:

```
public void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    g.setColor(); // <-- This line
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
```

I want to give my rectangle a color using RGB values like (200, 200, 200) for example; that'll be like a gray.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can get a Color instance with the simple code:

```
Color myWhite = new Color(255, 255, 255); // Color white
```

Then, you can set RGB color to your object with something like that:

```
g.setColor(myWhite);
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 7):

Or you can do:

```
setColor(new Color(r, g, b));
```

For example:

```
setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0)); //sets the color to Black
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `Graphics.setColor`

For example:

```
g.setColor(Color.getHSBColor(255, 79, 18));
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final Color VERY_LIGHT_GRAY = new Color(238,238,238);
```

and in your paintcomponent you add `g.setColor(VERY_LIGHT_GRAY);`

OR simply, `gc.setColor(new Color(238,238,238));`

check this website:
(https://teaching.csse.uwa.edu.au/units/CITS1001/colorinfo.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```java
bj1.setBackground(new Color(0, 62, 83));
bj2.setForeground(new Color(0, 00, 83));
bj3.setColor(new Color(0, 34, 83));
```

Alternatively, you can also pass Color object as parameter:

```java
Color c = new Color(Color.yellow);
obj4.setBackground(c);
```