# How to change color of JPanel with ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, applet

I'm learning basics of Java Applet and Swings. I'm trying a simple code. I want to change the color of my panel when a button is clicked. Here's the code:

**SimpleGui.java**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SimpleGui implements ActionListener {
    JFrame frame;
    JButton button;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleGui gui = new SimpleGui();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        button = new JButton("changes colour");
        button.addActionListener(this);

        MyPanel drawPanel = new MyPanel();

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,button);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,drawPanel);

        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    //event handling method
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        frame.repaint();
        button.setText("color changed");
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    public void paintCompenent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(20, 50, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

I added some `println` statements to debug and I found out that `paintComponent` method is not called. Can you please correct me. Where I am making mistake. Is my entire implementation is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paintComponent` must be `protected` (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics))).

change your code to :

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {
     protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(20, 50, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @Tanzeel can i know why you do all this?

Comment: I want to see how GUI of Java works. How things are implemented and how they react. I'm learning java gui basically.

Comment: But changes are happening as program loads, it should happen only when i press the button.

Comment: @Tanzeel Ok. Try to use some tools like `WindowBuilder` or equivalent ... it will be more simple

Comment: thanks @Landstalker, Can I add some `rgb` code in `g.setColor(Color.green);` so that with every click I can increment integer values like `count++` and thus apply a different color with every click?

Comment: Ok. I found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42855224/how-to-add-rgb-values-into-setcolor-in-java